# How to design editable grid using react-virtualized

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

How to design editable grid using react-virtualized.
I need a sandbox demo using react virtualized which can support large number of rows and columns with input boxes.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have taken the example from the demo page of **react-virtualized**.
Sadly It doesn't show the actual implemenation part.

https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/Grid

So I have prepared a sandbox to replicate this very scenario.

https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-keller-9fgn9